# Time Difference between events on different rows

Tags: mysql

I have tried many of the previously suggested ways to get the results I am looking for with no luck. Really new at this. In several of the instances, that were suggested in the past, I get an entire gambit of errors. Using MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE. Here is the table I am starting with and the table I wish to end with. Just looking for when the "status" goes <>0 till it returns to 0.

```
ndx  status t_stamp              machine_name
1    0      2013-09-06 05:45:24  
2    0      2013-09-06 05:52:57  BM01
3    165    2013-09-06 06:09:36  BM01
4    0      2013-09-06 06:09:57  BM01
5    165    2013-09-06 06:16:55  BM01
6    0      2013-09-06 06:17:14  BM01
7    165    2013-09-06 07:54:08  BM01
8    0      2013-09-06 07:54:23  BM01
9    165    2013-09-06 08:08:52  BM01
10   13     2013-09-06 08:27:10  BM01
11   99     2013-09-06 08:31:52  BM01
12   84     2013-09-06 09:09:28  BM01
13   255    2013-09-06 09:19:29  BM01
14   0      2013-09-06 09:19:33  BM01
15   2      2013-09-06 09:29:17  BM01
16   3      2013-09-06 09:33:07  BM01
17   0      2013-09-06 09:33:08  BM01
```

Some of the suggestions that seemed best to me were using different JOINs, but when I try them I get the red underline error. Using concat allows me to populate the target table but not correctly. This is a sub-query as it needs to do several machines.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pro_report_machine_status2`(IN StartDate DATETIME,IN EndDate DATETIME, IN Machine VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

SET @table_name = Machine;
SET @sql_text = 
concat('Insert Into tbl_machine_status1
        (machine_name,t_stamp)
        Select machine_name,t_stamp,TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,ign_bm01_status1_ndx,ign_bm01_status1_ndx+1)
        FROM ',@table_name,
        ' WHERE t_stamp >= "',StartDate,
        '" AND t_stamp <= "',EndDate,
        ' AND status <> 0 '
        '" Group By t_stamp asc;');

Prepare stmt From @sql_text;
Execute stmt;
Deallocate prepare stmt;

END
```

Forgot to add the actual question and the results table... soory

What Iwould like to return to a table is the amount of "downtime" which would be the amout of time the the machine was not at zero. So looking for code that says evaluate t_stamp (least value when not ZERO) - t_stamp (value when returns to zero). This would insert that time value into a table for each occurence.

```
ndx    downtime    machine_name
1      00:00:21    bm01
2      00:00:19    bm01
3      00:00:15    bm01
4      01:10:41    bm01
5      00:03:51    bm01
```

Hope this makes it clearer than mud. Really appreciate the assistance and THANKS!!!

Comment: The code and background is just fascinating.  What is the question?  Also, you mention the "table [you] wish to end with".  Please include that in the question too.

Comment: Where is the `ndx` value in your results table coming from? It's not the same as the `ndx` values in the events as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a couple of assumptions with this, so drop me a comment if I've got something wrong.

Basically, your big problem is you're assuming a sequence of events without identifying a "start" or "stop" event that you can go between. This is a common design flaw, and one you can work around by imposing a sequence and some logic. You could do this with user-variable hackery, but it's a problem better suited to cursors and/or application logic.

Here's a solution that uses a cursor:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE myproc(StartDate DATETIME,EndDate DATETIME, m VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    DECLARE cursorend INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE evtime DATETIME;
    DECLARE n INT;
    DECLARE prevstat INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE thisstat INT;
    DECLARE dur TIME;
    DECLARE start DATETIME;
    DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR 
       SELECT status, t_stamp, ndx
       FROM Machine 
       WHERE machine_name=m
         AND t_stamp BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
       ORDER BY t_stamp;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET cursorend = TRUE;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE outputtable(ndx INT, downtime TIME, machine_name VARCHAR(10));

    OPEN mycursor;

    myloop: LOOP
       FETCH mycursor INTO thisstat, evtime, n;
       IF cursorend THEN LEAVE myloop; END IF;
       IF thisstat = 0 AND prevstat <> 0 THEN 
          SET dur = TIMEDIFF(evtime, start);
          INSERT INTO outputtable VALUES(n, dur, m);
       ELSEIF thisstat <> 0 AND prevstat=0 THEN
          SET dur=0;
          SET start = evtime;
       END IF;
       SET prevstat=thisstat;
    END LOOP;
    SELECT * FROM outputtable;
    DROP TABLE outputtable;
    CLOSE mycursor;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

It goes through the rows one at a time (ordered by `t_stamp`), and triggers on two events:

- It assumes a "start" time when the *previous* status is 0 and the current status being non-zero.
- It assumes an "end" time when the previous status is non-zero and the current status is 0.

When the "start" event happens, it marks that time in a variable `start`.

When the "end" event happens, it gets the difference between that event's time and `start`, and calculates the duration, inserting it into a temporary table.

The output looks like this:

```
mysql> call myproc('2013-08-01', '2013-10-31','bm01');
+------+----------+--------------+
| ndx  | downtime | machine_name |
+------+----------+--------------+
|    4 | 00:00:21 | bm01         |
|    6 | 00:00:19 | bm01         |
|    8 | 00:00:15 | bm01         |
|   14 | 01:10:41 | bm01         |
|   17 | 00:03:51 | bm01         |
+------+----------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.41 sec)
```

Here, the `ndx` value matches that of the record with status `0`. If you want it sequential, as in your sample result, you could just set the `ndx` column to be auto-incrementing in the output table.

Comment: WOW! Never would have come up with anything like that in my life!When I tried to run the report, this is what I get: caused by Exception: Error executing system.db.execSProcCall()
 caused by GatewayException: Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE didata.myproc; expected 1, got 3
 caused by MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE didata.myproc; expected 1, got 3
And the incrementing was auto. Thanks!

Comment: That's because my proc only took the machine name, where your sample one took three parameters. I've edited mine to suit. Try it now.

Comment: Got a couple errors it didn't like. Made some other VERY small changes for purposes of running it, like the m VARCHAR it didn't like at (10). Now it keeps intermittently giving "outputtable doesn't exist". I tried removing the DROP at the end and put it before the Create Table and it seemed to like that better. But still, I could not find the "outputtable" in the schema data tables where they are created for all the other procedures. So I changed the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE to CREATE TABLE and now I have the table but it isn't populating?

Comment: The code I have here works as shown on my machine, when I call using the call statement shown. I've changed it on my machine to put a `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS outputtable;` before the `CREATE TABLE` (removed temporary), and now I can `SELECT * FROM outputtable` after running the proc. I'm not sure what you mean about `m VARCHAR` not working; like I say, it works as is given the sample data in your question. Can you be more specific about the errors you're having?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back. Very busy day, and I sure appreciate your help. This is the error I get when using m VARCHAR (10): caused by MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'm' at row 1. I believe due to my procedure's name. Then it didn't like the ndx and was only happy when I put the table name preceeding it, which is my fault for not catching that earlier as ndx is not the whole name, sorry. If I go in the schema and drop the existing outputtable, when I run the procedure from its report it executes and builds the table where I expect it, but with no data.

Comment: Oh no, that's one of the assumptions I made ;) You'll probably want `VARCHAR(50)` otherwise it won't find the machine name you pass in and will give you no rows. Not sure what you mean by `ndx` being different; your stored proc code has a column name that has `_bm01` in it, which sounds a bit odd, seeing as it's a machine name...